# Multi-Level type inference in C#

Tags: c#, generics, type-inference

I am wondering if there is a specific reason why the C# compiler does not seem to support two-level type inference on generics.

See the following code sample:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var instance = new GenericClass<object>();
        Test<GenericClass<object>, object>(instance); // works
        Test(instance); // Type arguments cannot be inferred
    }

    static void Test<TGenericClass, T>(TGenericClass obj) 
      where TGenericClass : IGenericClass<T>
    {

    }
}

public class GenericClass<T> : IGenericClass<T>
{
    public T Prop { get; set; }
}

public interface IGenericClass<T>
{
    T Prop { get; set; }
}
```

The compiler cannot infer that an object of type `GenericClass<object>` respects the type constraints, instead I have to specify the types manually. Is there a reason why the compiler does not support inference across multiple levels? How do you usually deal with it?

EDIT: Assume `TGenericClass` has to be generic.